# cannot checkout .gitattributes

Tags: git, gitattributes

I ran into an odd problem that I cannot checkout .gitattributes from remote. The .gitattributes file was recently added, and I want to pull it in and make some change. I did `git pull` and it said my branch is up to date but the file does not appear in my local machine (`ls -al` did not show .gitattributes). I tried to `git checkout origin .gitattributes`, it said it did not match any files. But if I do `git rm .gitattributes`, then `git status` shows that .gitattributes is staged for remove. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Edit:

```
$ git status
On branch YansBranch
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/YansBranch'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
// some file changes due to auto converting crlf to lf

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

$ ls -al
total 5
drwxr-xr-x      Administ     4096 Dec 23 12:11 .
drwxr-xr-x      Administ        0 Aug  5 16:38 ..
drwxr-xr-x      Administ     4096 Dec 23 12:13 .git
-rw-r--r--      Administ      955 Dec 23 10:57 .gitignore
drwxr-xr-x      Administ        0 Aug  5 16:39 win

$ git rm .gitattributes
rm '.gitattributes'

$ git status
On branch YansBranch
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/YansBranch'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        deleted:    .gitattributes

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
// some file changes due to auto converting crlf to lf
```

And here's my .gitattributes

```
# THIS IS ONLY FOR THE gitattributes REPOSITORY.
# Handle line endings automatically for files detected as text
# and leave all files detected as binary untouched.
* text=auto

#
# The above will handle all files NOT found below
#
# These files are text and should be normalized (Convert crlf => lf)
*.gitattributes text
.gitignore text
*.md text

# c++

#sources
*.C text
*.cc text
*.cxx text
*.cpp text
*.c++ text
*.hpp text
*.h text
*.h++ text
*.hh text

# Compiled Object files
*.slo binary
*.lo binary
*.o binary
*.obj binary

# Precompiled Headers
*.gch binary
*.pch binary

# Compiled Dynamic libraries
*.so binary
*.dylib binary
*.dll binary

# Compiled Static libraries
*.lai binary
*.la binary
*.a binary
*.lib binary

# Executables
*.exe binary
*.out binary
*.app binary

# c#
*.cs     diff=csharp
```

Comment: This isn't clear - what are you actually trying to achieve?  Undo local changes to a file, pull remote changes to that file, something else?

Comment: (Also, AFAIK `git checkout origin .gitattributes` isn't meaningful...)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, I'm trying to modify .gitattributes, but when I pulled from remote, the I couldn't find it on my local machine.

Comment: To clarify, you're saying that `ls -al` does *not* list `.gitattributes`?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth that's correct

Comment: This is difficult to decipher without more concrete evidence - Can you add console output to your question, that shows the following sequence: `git status` (showing no local changes), `ls -al`, `git rm .gitattributes`, `git status`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth please see the edit

Comment: Ok I can't explain that.  The only thing I can think of is that actually `.gitattributes` is buried in the list of files you've omitted from the first `git status`.  i.e. You'd already somehow done `rm .gitattributes` before all of this.  That would explain why it doesn't show up in `ls -al`, but you'd still be able to do `git rm .gitattributes` without error.